# Is my string interpolation secure in Jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am referring to the link [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables). Below is part of my script code which goes to a platform with username and password to get an auth token.

```
...
...
   environment{
      CRED = credentials("my_cred")
   }
...
...
   sh'''
   token = $(curl --fail -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST https://google.com -d 
   \'{"username":"'"$CRED_USR"'","password":"'"$CRED_PSW"'"}\') 
   '''
   //prints in console '{"username":"*****","password":"*****"}'
...
...
```

If i just pass below then it does not work. I think the body needs to be stringified before sending.

```
"username":CRED_USR,"password":CRED_PSW
or
"username":'$CRED_USR',"password":'$CRED_PSW'
```

This works but is it secure?

```
"username":"'$CRED_USR'","password":"'$CRED_PSW'" 
// prints in console '{"username":"*****","password":"*****"}'
```

Can someone please let me know if I my code is secure or not from string interpolation point of view? If not then please let me know the right way to do it.

Comment: `sh(curl ...` is not a valid code. Using Env variables is a right way. But you don't need to interpolate them for sh command.

Comment: do you want to say that there is no quotes or doublequotes after `sh(` and it works for you? and article that you are referencing is saying that you should not interpolate env variable with password - just pass it as name to sh script.

Comment: @daggett Apologies for confusion!! Edited the snippet. As mentioned in the question, if you pass it directly then it does not work. I have already mentioned what and how i have tried. The article mentions _Using single-quotes instead of double-quotes when referencing these sensitive environment variables prevents this type of leaking._ So i want to know if the way i am passing it is secure or not?

Answer (score 0):

it's not secure because when you are interpolating password on the level of groovy it could appear in logs and someone who has access to logs could see the password.

this should work:

```js
environment{
   CRED_USR = ...
   CRED_PSW = ...
}
...

sh '''
    curl ... '{"username":"$CRED_USR","password":"$CRED_PSW"}' ... 
'''
```

Comment: anything received using ```credentials()``` method will be automatically masked in logs so that's not an issue.